# VIM-LaTeX F5 package insertion problem

Tags: vim-latex

When I insert a package into my preamble in VIM-LaTeX using F5 and select for instance `floatflt`, instead of `\usepackage{floatflt}`, I often get the following. How can I solve this?

```
<++>]{floatflt}"`usepackage[X
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. It has also been referenced [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/vim-latex/mailman/message/26741053/) in the year 2010 and [here](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/issues/9) much more recently. As far as I undertood, there' s no answer yet.

Comment: Another reference [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/vim-latex/mailman/message/6174983/)

Comment: This appears to be raised (initally by the OP) and is listed as resolved on github (https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/issues/9).  I guess advice now would be update vim-latex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem does not occur anymore, assumably because of the `vim-latex` update mentioned by @Dai-Bowen.